# When is it bad form to return a deferred IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm curious if anyone has any rules-of-thumb or best practices on when it makes sense to return a deferred `IEnumerable<T>` or to call `ToArray()` on it before returning it from a function.

For example, as the consumer of an API I think that I would prefer for a method like `IEnumerable<Widget> GetWidgets()` to throw an `HttpException` when I call it and not have it throw when I'm enumerating the results.

```
public IEnumerable<Widget> GetWidgets(IEnumarable<int> widgetIds) {
    return widgetIds.Select(id => GetWidgetFromWidgetWebService(id));
}
```

Comment: I can't think of a single time I've ever wanted to return a deferred IEnumerable and plenty when I've done it by accident and broken all sorts of code.

Comment: But, shouldn't the exception by thrown either way? At least in that case they would work the same way.

Comment: @rae1n Yes, the exception would be thrown either way, but imagine an deffered `IEnumerable<Widget>` being passed through a layer or two only to have an exception thrown at a call-site far removed from where the original collection was returned.

Comment: Pardon my naivety. If this is for a web service, I don't know how one can do a delayed return? i.e. I am assuming things because of `HttpException` in your question.

Comment: Good question btw! I personaly decide this depending on the situation. When a collection is used which is likly to change i never return a deffered enumerable.

Comment: @shahkalpesh In my example, as the returned `IEnumerable<Widget>` is iterated, it will call `GetWidgetFromWidgetWebService()`, so there is a possibility for each iteration of the enumerator to throw an exception.

Comment: @joshperry: I am sorry, I cannot wrap my head on this. Can a web api return IEnumerable<T> which is a delayed one?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I think josh was thinking of calling the web service multiple times, each call returning one widget...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Is such a thing possible on web using API? I am sure, I am missing something.

Comment: @shahkalpesh He's saying a client-side API that calls a web service - not a single call to the web API...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I understand that there will be as many calls made as there are widgets. However, is such a thing possible without some kind of state being managed on server, specifically for APIs?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Sure - you can call this one at a time from the client, since you're passing each ID one at a time.

Comment: @shahkalpesh No, no state is required. The only thing you need to make a request for an object to a REST endpoint is the URL. HTTP by its very design is stateless. In my iterator example, the variable state is being carried by the implementation of `Select` (possibly an iterator block) memoizing the widget ID collection, passing each ID to my lambda as it is iterated.

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Silly me. I thought the code is a web method, API for clients to call. Made me think, how does one return a deferred thing from a webservice?

Answer (score 6):

I always prefer returning a deferred `IEnumerable<T>` when there are not significant side effects of it being deferred.  If the enumerable is based on an internal collection that may likely change, for example, I would prefer to evaluate it first.

However, if the enumerable is being computed, etc, then I would typically defer it.

Comment: The caller can always call `ToList()` and force immediate evaluation if desired. I think it's best to let the caller make this choice, unless, as you said, there is good reason not to.

Comment: @JonB That's my thought - I prefer to allow the optimizations when possible.

Comment: One exception would be when you're passing the `IEnumerable` into a context where it will not be _possible_ to enumerate it. For instance, when the `IEnumerable<T>` was generated using an EF context which will have been disposed by the time of enumeration. Other than that, I agree that leaving it deferred is better for composition.

Comment: @JonB The only problem with that is, returning `IEnumerable<T>` only tells the caller "Hey, here's an interface to go through a list of things of type T" it doesn't communicate that it may be deferred or not. I don't know how the caller could have enough information to make an informed decision on whether to materialize the list ASAP.

Comment: @joshperry Documentation helps here.  That being said, I don't feel that it's enough reason to **always** evaluate it fully, as there are often significant advantages, especially with larger enumerations, to having things deferred.  I hate seeing an API that's being evaluated unnecessarily get used via `.Any()`, for example (which isn't uncommon)...

Comment: @JohnSaunders That's basically what I was saying - if there is going to be a significant side effect that will cause problems, I'll evaluate.  A disposed EF context is a good example.

Answer (score 1):

In case your enumerable can be practically expected to throw, eagerly evaluate it (if at all possible). You don't want the error to occur at a remote place that is unrelated to the cause of the error. You want the error right where it was caused.

After all, the method did not complete what its name advertises, so it should throw.

I usually change the return type to `IList<T>` in such cases to document that it executes eagerly.

Comment: I really like trying to be expressive with my code, implying intent if you will. The only problem I have with returning `IList<T>` in those cases is that it says "Hey, this is a mutable collection". I'm not sure what a better option is; maybe `T[]`, maybe `IReadOnlyList<T>`?

Comment: @joshperry I very much tend to not modify collections so I don't have that problem. I usually create a new one which is dead easy since C# 3.0.

Comment: There's nothing to say that an `IList<T>` is executed eagerly. It's quite possible, and often desirable, to have an `IList<T>` that only executes what is necessary as it is necessary.

Comment: @JonHanna sure that's possible but in my experience it is unusual. I cannot name a single BCL class that does this and I have never done it myself. I think IList is a good way of documenting eagerness because there is no other good way to document it.

Comment: I've done it because I wanted to buffer results for subsequent reuse without wasting time on the first retrieval, or when I was likely to want to do something with the first few elements, but only sometimes load the whole thing. If I wanted to be demonstrably eagerly-loaded, I'd return `List<T>` or another concrete class. After all, once of the reasons for returning any interface is to say "just how I did this, is not your concern, and may change in the future"; precisely the opposite of making how you did something clear.